How to pass a value down the call stack in Scala Play app
I need to pass some information down the call stack in a Scala Play application.
For example:
class FooController: play.api.mvc.BaseController {
  ...
  def method1(request: play.mvc.Http.Request) = {
    // Somehow store the request.callerId
    // I need to access it whenever I need to know the caller. For example, I will need it for some logging.
    fooService.method2()
  }
}

class FooService {
  ...
  def method2() = fooRepository.method3()
}

class FooRepository {
  ...
  def method3() = {
    // I want to access the callerId to log who made the changes
  }
}

I need to know who started the call down the call stack. Is it possible without changing the code and adding extra parameters to all methods?
Note: I use Scala 2.13 and play 3.0

Short partial answer: no, you have to make this callerId a parameter propagated downstream in every method (it can be an implicit parameter though). If this is for logging purposes only, I think I've seen people making MDC stuff working in Scala so that it's handled for you by the framework.

I see, thanks for your answer. I need it for logging purposes only but my setup is a bit different. I plan to persist the caller in a database table column so that our CDC pipeline catches all update and create actions, and logs them.
